# How to select content of a tag in Aptana?

Tags: select, tags, aptana

Is it possible to highlight the content of a tag in Aptana with some key combination?[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible pressing on top tag... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (only works with some versions) and to select all internal data tags press on top tag .. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> then press <kbd>2</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

To be hone I don't think so, but you can try by clicking on the start of the tag and press shift+ down arrow, or close the tag (see the - next to the line number?) press it and it will summarise the tag, and you can just highlight it all by selecting the summary.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+.
Or right click on the tag, commands, HTML, Select tag pair and content.